# Can 4 sticks of memory reduce CPU life?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

In my experience (AM2+) it just seems like 4 sticks is unstable at any setting. I believe that running 4 @ 1066 5-5-5-15 (which is what the memory is rated for) has caused them to go bad. I started getting MEMORY_MANAGEMENT blue screens.

I ran MemTest86+ at 1066 and got 300 errors in one pass but underclocked to 800 and the errors disappeared. That or the IMC is taking a dump. Another PC in the house (AM3+, FX 6300) is running 4 sticks at 1600 9-9-9-24 and appears to be stable. (My father doesn't play system intensive games though.)

Does he have anything to worry about? I was thinking of getting him to give me two of his sticks for my new processor/mobo I'll be buying if he is unknowingly reducing his systems life.

Comment: If you use only two sticks, do they run at the rated speed? ( without error? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.

More memory sticks = more heat generated. If the casing's airflow is not good enough, then that will drive the CPU's operating temperature = higher chance of failure.

On the other hand, the errors you see might be caused by many factors:

- Bad memory stick
- Local overheating due to obstructed airflow
- Corroded contacts on one (or more) of the memory slots
- Bad / unstable motherboard components

For the first point, bring your memory sticks to someone with a known-good setup (4 sticks working well), and test with MemTest86+.

Another way to test would be to test the sticks **one by one, on the same slot**.

If all the sticks fail, test on another slot. If all the sticks pass, test the other slots.

For the second point, use cable ties (either the plastic "one-way" tab version or a velcro one -- I prefer the latter) to tidy up the cabling inside the case. You might also need to rearrange the PCI cards. And perhaps, buy a dedicated exhaust fan for the casing (late-model ones usually reserve a space to attach a 10- or 12-cm exhaust fan).

Comment: I believe my airflow is sufficient so I'm not entirely sure it's a heat issue. These parts are 6 years old so it might be their time to go. :) I'm going to be getting replacement components soon anyways so I'm not even worried anymore. Basically I was just curious.

Comment: You mean "not *directly*"?

Comment: @psusi you caught me there :-) ... a case of the brain thinking about synonyms and the fingers dumping the mind :-D

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely that 4 sticks of memory will make the CPU go bad [ any more then 1 or 2 sticks would ] - infact, if you look at really powerful systems they typically have lots of memory banks.

It sounds simply like (at least one of) your memory sticks is faulty.